# Database Connection with Jenkins (On Yii)

Tags: php, jenkins, yii, junit, phpunit

Giving this in the **Execute Shell:**

```
phpunit protected/tests/unit/LoginFormTest.php -c protected/tests/phpunit.xml --log-junit junit-results/phpunit.xml
```

It is not able to establish the database connection

Giving  a long message with this line ..

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'CDbException' with message
>   'CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection.'

I have give credentials in the configuring jenkins.
What can be the problem.?

Comment: It's not connected with jenkins. But I think it's connected with database configuration. Can you connect to database using console?

Comment: Yes. I am able to connect from the console.

Comment: I think you should update your configuration on tests, because probably jenkins uses different credentials.